# a:hover background replacement on a empty a tag not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Im using hyperlinks as a image, well a background image so that I can do a image swap eaisly with a:hover.

I have the following:

```
<a class="cross" href='#'></a>
```

And the following css

```
a.cross {
    background:transparent url(/images/cross-grey.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    display: block;
}

a:hover.cross {
    background-position: 0 20px;

}
```

This works fine in Firefox but not in IE6. Is this a issue with IE6 and a simple css fix or is there a better way of implementing what I am doing. Thanks.

Comment: Was your problem solved? You have to accept answers if they're helpful.

Comment: I changed my css however IE6 still doesn't excecute the image swap, well background position change.

Comment: Thats another issue then, will need a separate post with your new code, html and possibly a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
a:hover.cross { }
```

To:

```
a.cross:hover { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should deal the a:hover.cross with javascript.

Regards.